# Reset the asp.net mvc routes without resetting the app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to stroe my routes in DB and register them in Application_Start of Global.asax.cs. Everything is fine but any change in the DB, I have to reset the app in order to let app to pick up my changes.

If i can reset the routes without restart the app, the problem will be solved. 
How would I achive it geeks? A custom httpmodule? or...

Comment: I'd be very interested to see your db-based solution for storing routes this way. I've seen some examples online but they're generally rubbish, or just not enough.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static void UpdateRouteRegistration() {
  RouteCollection routes = RouteTable.Routes;
  using (routes.GetWriteLock()) {
    routes.Clear();
    // repopulate route table here
  }
}
```

Then call this method from Application_Start and any other time you need to initialize the route table.  Note: This is from memory and might be slightly mistyped, but you get the idea. :)

Comment: I am looking for this answer since sometime I started up, I haven't yet tested this solution though, but sounds cool, but could there be an impact otherwise lets say the reset happens when some other transaction is on? if this is a blog kinda project so ok but may not be suitable for other types where the transactions are critical, just my thoughts through..

Answer (score -4):

daft answer, routes cannot be added without app restart and calling UpdateRouteRegistration() without restart will clear routes so you'll end up throwing errors on each and every request.